# AccessViolationException when trying to show an MDI Child form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, mdi

I am working on a 64-bit MDI Winforms application. When the application starts, it proceeds to load a LOT of data -- the process memory is sitting at around 9 GB when fully loaded.

After loading, the user can select one of a number of forms, which are displayed as MDI children.

```
  SomeForm f = new SomeForm(); // Oops. v1 of this question had null here! Edited to correct this.
  f.MdiParent = this; // Boom! AccessViolationException
  f.Show();
```

This is how I'm instantiating and showing the child form. This is exactly how I have done it dozens of times, except now I'm getting an AccessViolationException when that second line is executed. Anyone have any idea why this is giving me a problem? Some thoughts:

1. 64-bit Winforms. It's possible that the MDI functionality under 64-bit Windows just really hasn't been tested properly. MDI is a bit old-fashioned.
2. Some issue with DEP (Data Execution Prevention) -- is there some kind of internal limit to the process size, beyond which DEP malfunctions?
3. Some kind of threading problem. The aforementioned 8+ GB of data is being loaded via a new Thread() object. This calls back to the host form frequently to update on progress, which the host form displays appropriately. (The UI code is wrapped in an Invoke statement). Once the data load process completes, the thread terminates;

Unlikely scenarios, but I'm clutching at straws.

Comment: I can tell you it isn't (1). 64-bit Winforms/CLR is mature.

Comment: Right, I have fixed this. My form had a GreatMaps component on it (GMap.NET); and I believe this is compiled with Any CPU, as opposed to x64. So (and this is purely conjecture) when my data has finished loading, the gmap assembly attempts to load in an area of memory that can't be referenced with 32 bits. Does this sound like what's happening? The fix was to simply create that form before filling up my memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the `new SomeForm()` doesn't fail in the constructor?

In that case you're trying to set `Disposed` object's property in this line:

`f.MdiParent = this;`

Comment: The constructor is not failing.

Comment: As it turns out, the constructor wasn't failing; but when I substituted `Form` for `SomeForm`, everything worked as expected. Strange. Nothing runs in the constructor, except setting up the Shown event handler. I am using the GreatMaps.NET component, and I suspect there's a problem somewhere in that.

Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

You have to *create a instance* of the `SomeForm` class

```
  SomeForm f = new SomeForm(); // <- instead of " = null"
  f.MdiParent = this; // <- that's quite OK to assign value to the isntacne
  f.Show();
```

Comment: Well spotted; that's actually what my code does. The code snippet I put up was in error -- I have updated the question.

Comment: So it still crashes? Please note your edit in the question! Also: From which event is the code?

Comment: This code is simply in a button event handler. Couldn't be simpler.